# Can't get values from sqlite and set into TextView

Tags: android, sqlite

I was wondering what wrong with my code bellow, why i can't set values from sqlite in colums #5 setText into TextView?

```
//Adapter SQLite
public Cursor getFRUIT_LEVEL_EASY_STEP_2()
{
    Cursor step_2 = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM FRUIT WHERE " + KEY_LEVEL + "='Easy' AND " + KEY_LEVEL_STEP + "=1", null); 
    return step_2;
}

final TextView l1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.l1);
mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();

step_2 = mySQLiteAdapter.getFRUIT_LEVEL_EASY_STEP_2();
step_2.moveToFirst();

int count2 = step_2.getInt(0);

// Here i want to get value Int from clumns #5
int score =step_2.getInt(5);

if(count2 != 0)
    {
        l1.setText(Integer.toString(score));

    }

 step_2.close();
 mySQLiteAdapter.close();
```

Why I can't get the value? what's wrong in this code?

Comment: you really called amethod getFRUIT_LEVEL_EASY_STEP_2() that is horrible, theres no reason a method should be called that, there is a reason why there are standard and that it to make your code, nice and readable.

Comment: For `colums #5` try `step_2.getInt(4)` instead ! and to get better solution also post the `logcat`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code

```
l1.setText(String.valueOf(score));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of l1.setText(Integer.toString(score));

use l1.setText(""+Integer.toString(score));

may this help you